# React Hooks: Component is not rendering in Nested Routing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am using `"react-scripts": "4.0.2"` and all my components are React Hooks. My logic involves nested routing but the end result is not rendered.

**App.js:**

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div className="App">
    <TopNav />
    <Home />
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

**Home.js:**

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/" component={Questions} />
</Switch>
```

**Questions.js**

```
    const displayQuestion = (qid) => {
         props.history.push({ pathname: "/question/" + qid });
      };
    
//questions is an array of objects

      const questionsBlocks = questions.map((quest, i) => {
        return (
          <QBlock
            key={i + 1}
            qno={i + 1}
            displayQuestion={displayQuestion.bind(this, quest.qid)}
          />
        );
      });
    
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Questions</h1>
          {questionsBlocks}
          <Switch>
            <Route
              path="/question/:id"
              render={(props) => <Question {...props} questions={questions} />}
            />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      );
```

QBlock will only render buttons that will call `displayQuestion` on being clicked

**QBlock.js:**

```
  return (
    <div className="block" onClick={props.displayQuestion}>
      <h1>{props.qno}</h1>
    </div>
  );
```

**Question.js:**

```
const [question, setQuestion] = useState();

  const loadQuestion = () => {
    console.log(props);
    if (props.match.params.id) {
      console.log("load called");
      const qid = props.match.params.id;
      const index = props.questions.findIndex((quest) => quest.qid == qid);
      setQuestion(props.questions[index]);
    }
  };

  // componentDidMount with react hooks
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Mounted");
    loadQuestion();
  }, []);

  // componentDidUpdate with react hooks
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Updated");
    loadQuestion();
  }, [props.match.params.id]); //Even tried with only props

  return (
    <div className="Quest">
      <div className="question">{question.question}</div>
      <div className="options">{question.answerChoices}</div>
    </div>
  );
```

Neither of the `useEffect` of `Question.js` is not executing still I am getting the following error.

[image]

Comment: the useState is undefined.

Comment: @Vince Don't know what happened, as soon as I added `const options = question.answerChoices.map((opt) => <div>{opt}</div>);` in `Question.js` before return() it gave me an error stating `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. It was working fine for a while. I think there is same problem i.e. my `useEffect` is not executing on rendering or updating. But I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, `question` needs to be initialized

```
const [question, setQuestion] = useState(null);
```

And another thing you need to do is to check the value of `question` before using it

```
return (
    <div className="Quest">
      {question && question.question && <div className="question">{question.question}</div>}
      {question && question.answerChoices && <div className="options">{question.answerChoices}</div>}
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

As Vince said.. I had defined `useState` like `const [question, setQuestion] = useState();` instead of `const [question, setQuestion] = useState({});`